# Trying to get some useful data from a log file with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, logging

I'm having trouble with regex, because I can only match some of my goals.

I have a log file and I must match some of the items and write another txt file. I wrote a Java code for a short example of my code but when I put the whole file, everything gets messed up.

```
*052511 074217 0065            02242806000      UNKNOWN         U G

*052511 074217 0065    4874    02242806000      UNKNOWN         U A

*052511 074218 0065    4874    02242806000      UNKNOWN         U R

--------   05/25/11   07:42:17   LINE = 0065   STN = 4874    

   CALLING NUMBER   02242806000

   NAME             UNKNOWN        

   UNKNOWN

   BC = SPEECH

00:00:00   INCOMING CALL    RINGING 0:02

00:00:11   CALL RELEASED
```

I have to find these results from the file:

> incomming,05/25/11,07:42:17,0065,4874,02242806000,00:00:09,2

In this expression `00:00:09` means `[00:00:11-00:00:00]-0:02`

For every incoming and outgoing calls, I must make the conversation above.

- [Here is my code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-LLfa9uP7oDestzh-bf3YW1xj6e8MmmxGgpJWJ0K7Vk/edit?hl=en_US)
- [Here is the log file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gkkfTZhX2BtFem3vQ1X9VCTv50P-s9NHfFdaRn8tfvM/edit?hl=en_US)

Comment: On a side note, use StringBuilder if you have something like `str += str2` in a loop.

Comment: Is the format very strict on the log file? Like, will there ever be deviations in its format? Are you only trying to capture incoming call records? Is the log ever any larger than your example? I have a solution in mind for you but I need a bit more information before I write anything out.

Comment: @TheCapn I give the log file in my question. It's : http://goo.gl/cm75n
I'm trying to get both incoming calls and outgoing calls. Log has a repetition in its format.

Comment: My question wasn't *for* the log file it was *about* the log file. Essentially what I want to propose to you is to drop the idea of regex entirely as its needlessly complicated for a simple problem where you could easily read in the values you desire to an object class and discard the data if it is not for a relevent incoming/outgoing call. All you're looking for is certain fields that are in static locations and context so using regex to pull out dynamic data is hardly necessary

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like:

```
(?xm:
^-------- \s+ (\S+) \s+ (\S+) \s+ LINE\s*=\s*(\d+) \s+ STN\s*=\s*(\d+)
\s+ CALLING\ NUMBER \s+ (\d+) \s*
(?:^(?:[ \t]+.*)?[\n\r]+)* # eat unwanted part

^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \s+ INCOMING\ CALL \s+ RINGING\ ([\d:]+) \s*
(?:^\d.*[\r\n]+)* # possible stuff
^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \s+ CALL\ RELEASED
)
```

Use the values of the capturing groups to get your results. You may need to remove the `/x` related things like comments and spaces.

Perl example at http://ideone.com/qTBFe

Comment: thank you for all. It works on Perl but I couldn't make it on Java. Should I read the file line by line?

Comment: This one works on the whole file, not line by line (because what you want to find spans several lines). If it fits in memory, read in the file and run the regex on the containing string.